Shoresh Neshama
When we say shoresh neshama, is there a different root for each level of the soul (nefesh, ruach, neshama) or only for the level of the neshama?
For exemple, Arizal says that Nadav ben Aharon has only his ruach from the level of Kayin but his nefesh came from his elder Aminadav.
So what is his shoresh neshama?
Do we have only one or several shorshei neshama?

The Nefesh, Ruach and Neshama can all have a different shoresh. Source: Shaar Hagilgulim 1-4

Okay thank you So, which part of the soul the Arizal refered when he said in Shaar Kavanot : "For in accordance with the source and root of the souls of that tribe, so must be its prayer rite."?

Thank you Rabbi Kaii, this is more clear. So it means in the exemple given of Nadav ben Aharon, his soulroot is from the tribe of Yehuda (of Aminadav) and not from Levi (his crurent tribe)?

@חיים I've cleared the comments now as you read the and I don't think we need them anymore
